# Where is the Geany user directory on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, path, geany

I can't find Geany's (http://www.geany.org/) user config dir on Win7. It does not seem to be in ProgramData or ~/AppData/Local

Apparently, Windows 7 also has lost the ability to find directories (or is this a matter of the indexing options?).

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Apparently, Windows 7 also has lost the ability to find directories "...I have no problems finding them in W7?

Comment: Well, I searched for "geany" but no directory was found. Fileseek did the trick, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it with Fileseek
~/AppData/Roaming/geany

~ means your user directory

Comment: +1 Thank you; (the manual of Geany should be updated)